# How to authenticate login in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to create login form with react and mongoDB

here is my controller:

```
authenticate: function (req, res, next) {
    Admin.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, function (err, adminInfo) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, adminInfo.password)) {
                const token = jwt.sign({
                        id: adminInfo._id
                    },
                    req.app.get("secretKey"), {
                        expiresIn: "1h"
                    }
                );
                res.json({
                    status: "success",
                    message: "admin found!!!",
                    data: {
                        user: adminInfo,
                        token: token
                    },
                });
            } else {
                res.json({
                    status: "error",
                    message: "Invalid email/password!!!",
                    data: null,
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my LoginForm.jsx:

```
const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [routeRedirect, setRouteRedirect] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const admin = {
      username,
      password,
    };
    axios
      .post("/login/authenticate", admin)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.errors) {
          setError(true);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    setRouteRedirect(true);
  };
  return (
    <ContactWrapper>
      <ContactContainer>
        {routeRedirect ? (
          <Fragment>Hello</Fragment>
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            <Title>LOGIN</Title>
            <LoginForm onSubmit={login}>
              <FormLabel>Username:</FormLabel>
              <FormInput
                type="text"
                name="username"
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              />
              <FormLabel>Password:</FormLabel>
              <FormInput
                type="password"
                name="password"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
              <LoginButton type="submit">Login</LoginButton>
            </LoginForm>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </ContactContainer>
    </ContactWrapper>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

How can I authenticate username and password when click on button?
I tried to put in wrong password and wrong username and it still give me the "Hello"
How can I fix this?

Thank you

Here is my github project if you want to look over my code:
https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you call "setRouteRedirect(true)" no matter the result of the api call.

You should probably setRouteRedirect in the then function of your post if the result satisfies you.

This call

```
axios
  .post("/login/authenticate", admin)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.data.errors) {
      setError(true);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Does not block the code, so after sending the request, setRouteRedirect will be called.

Comment: What should I replace it ?

Comment: You probably should use setTouteRedirect in the "then" function, replacing "return null". With that you will change to the correct route when you get the response without errors